# User Principal in Entity Framework Core DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am upgrading a project from .NET 4.6 to .NET Core. It is an ASP.NET MVC website with a WebAPI that uses EntityFramework. When the a (MVC or WebAPI) Controller fires up the DbContext, there is code that needs to identity the user as a ClaimsIdentity to inspect their claims.  In previous .NET, this was most reliably available on Thread.CurrentPrincipal like this:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

IIRC, this was the safest way to do it since you could be coming from different contexts - WebAPI or ASP.NET MVC.

In the .NET core solution, I have tried to Dependency Inject an IHttpContextAccessor into the constructor, but the User on HttpContext is not authorized and has no claims

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;
// identity.IsAuthenticated == false. identity.Claims is empty.
```

Security is wired up in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
                AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                }).
                AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;

                    var key = Configuration["Tokens:Key"];

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
                    };
                });
```

The user logins on a /Login MVC view page, which logs in via Cookies and also generates a Bearer token in another request that is saved on the client. After all this the user is redirected to the homepage.

Cookie Login:

```
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = bIsPersistent });
```

Token Generation (called from ajax, saved to localstorage before redirection)

```
var secretKey = Configuration["Tokens:Key"];
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256 );
var expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
    _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
    oAuthIdentity.Claims,
    expires: expires,
    signingCredentials: creds
    );

ret = Ok(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
```

After landing on the homepage, an ajax call is made to the WebApi with the  bearer token (I pulled the bearer token out of the http request and verified the signature on jwt.io), and the webapi causes the DbContext to be instantiated, and this is where the identity is not valid.

It's as if the Identity is not properly marshalled over to the DbContext -

**How to I get the correct User or Identity in the DbContext?**

Additionally, at the point I need it is in the DbContext construction, which I don't have alot of control over with the Dependency Injection.  But I need to get this info basically from a default constructor or lazy load it somehow.

Comment: Is your call to `httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity` occurring within the same *request* as the call to `HttpContext.SignInAsync`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin - No, and I left out some details, I'll update the question. The login happens from a login View the login also gets a bearer token which is saved on the client side. After login the user is redirected to the homepage and from here this token is passed with a call to the API Controller, which instantiates the DbContext.

Comment: your usage of `User` property is fine. Within your constructor, you can also directly use `User` without any injection. These will work as long as your authentication is set right. Post the relevant code from your startup class

Comment: how are you calling using the `AuthorizeAttribute` over the controller/action? are you specifying the scheme name?

Comment: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes =    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

Answer (score 0):

With your setup, you have two authentications setup. So, in your `ConfigureServices` function in Startup class, you need to use something like the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie().AddJwtBearer();
```

Don't forget to specify a default authentication. For instance, if you want the authentication to be cookies by default, you can use this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Cookies").AddCookie().AddJwtBearer();
```

Or to keep the code safer,

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie().AddJwtBearer();
```

In your startup class, in the `Configure` function, don't forget to add

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

When authenticating within a controller, you will need to use the scheme name along with the `[Authorize]` if you are not using the default scheme.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "")]
```

Comment: my setup matches this but still having issues.  Thank you

Comment: can you include the authentication related code for your startup.cs and the controller where you use Authorize? and when you say you verified a token, how did you verify it?

Comment: I think I have added all the details you requested

Comment: So, first of all are you able go past the authorize attribute?

Comment: @SalvadorIvanMolinaMolina i think it makes more sense to post that comment under his question